# react-native run-android error: Unable to upload some APKs

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, apk

When I'm trying to upload react-native apk on my phone, I get an error:

```
:app
:installDebug                                                                  

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Unable to upload some APKs

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Did you follow the [Running on device](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html) doc? It's important that you write udev rules.

Answer (score 1):

First, check if your device is plugged in:

```
adb devices
```

Then check the gradle version. Version **1.3.1** is [well known](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html#shell-command-unresponsive-exception) to cause this problem. To fix it, go to *android/build.gradle* and change the version to **1.2.3**.

Comment: google a lots of answers, and this one should be the correct answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because I was using Node v5.0.
Switching to Node v6.6 solved it for me.